# iterating through all items in listA that don't appear in listB

Tags: python

How can I fix this statement:

```
for i in LISTA and i not in LISTB:
   print i
```

Comment: i'm not sure of the best syntax here, but you could just nest an if

Comment: Please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you S.lott, no homework here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new_list = set(LISTA) -  set(LISTB) # if you don't have duplicate
for i in new_list:
   print i
```

Or :

```
for i in LISTA:
   if i in LISTB:
      continue
   print i
```

Comment: I can only upvote in a few minutes, but this list subtraction solves my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sets are awesome if you don't need your duplicates to remain. Also might be important to point out that `new_list` is a set not a list.

Comment: Sets also lose ordering.  The efficient thing to do in general is to only create a set for `listb`, where ordering and duplicates never matter, so `i in listb` is efficient.

Answer (score 8):

```
for i in LISTA:
  if i not in LISTB:
    print i
```

Answer (score 5):

A more sophisticated solution. This is a simple intersection complement.

```
a = set([1, 2, 3])
b = set([3, 4, 5])

print(a - b)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in (i for i in LISTA if i not in LISTB):
    print i
```

The part in parentheses is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). The benefit of this over other methods that is that it doesn't create duplicate (temporary) sets or list objects. This is especially important if LISTA and/or LISTB are really large.